# Replace character with _ in C

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to create a program in C that replaces a character in a string with  **_**.

```
int main(){   
    replace("hello");  
    return 0;  
}

void replace(const char secret[]){
    int seret_lenght = strlen(secret);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<seret_lenght; i++){
        if(secret[i] == 'h'){
            secret[i] = '_';
        }
    }  
    printf("%s", secret);
}
```

The result should be:

> _ello

But terminal print only hello.

Comment: `secret[i] = '_';` (your compiler could have warned you!)

Comment: `"hello"` is of type `const char*`. You can't modify it.

Comment: Please raise the warning level of your compiler to the maximum, and I'm sure it will tell you that you cannot assign to a `const char`. Beware, even if you change the parameter data type, you are passing a `const char []` from `main()`. You need to change this, too.

Comment: When I remove const and add secret[i] = '_'; console shows Segmentation fault and print nothing.

Comment: That's because [`"hello"` is of type const char*. You can't modify it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69809462/replace-character-with-in-c#comment123397660_69809462)

Comment: @david You may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comment replace `secret[i] == '_';`.  Operator `==` is used to compare two values only.  Operator `=` is used for assigning a value.  Also, the parameter is an array of `const`.  The `const` must be removed if you intend to write to the array.